# Error Code: 1054. Unknown column 'likes' in 'field list'

Tags: mysql, mysql-error-1064

my requirement is get average of like.

```
SELECT 
    COALESCE(SUM(type = 1), 0) AS likes,
    COALESCE(SUM(type = 2), 0) AS dislikes,
    count(type) as total_like,
    likes / dislikes, // Error on this line
    e_id  
FROM `e_rating` 
group by e_id 
order by e_id ASC
```

**Note:** Get average using only single query.

Answer (score 4):

You [can't reference your previous aliases](https://dba.stackexchange.com/questions/96556/reference-column-alias-in-same-select-list), so you need to write out the full statements:

```
SELECT 
    COALESCE(SUM(type = 1), 0) AS likes,
    COALESCE(SUM(type = 2), 0) AS dislikes,
    count(type) as total_like,
    COALESCE(SUM(type = 1), 0) / COALESCE(SUM(type = 1), 0) AS average,
    e_id  
FROM `e_rating` 
group by e_id 
order by e_id ASC
```